# Using npm in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, npm, ntvs

When using `npm` in Visual Studio with NTVS, what are the options that are in effect? How do I apply `--save` or `-g`?

Will it corrupt the Visual Studio project in anyway if I were to run `npm` outside of Visual Studio on the command line directly?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say anything about *ntvs*, because I've never used it. But when we are talking about standard *Package Manager Console Window*:

1. ***npm install [packageName]*** - installs packages *locally* (analogue to ***--save*** option);
2. npm uses *package.json* file of the selected project;
3. to understand weather ***using npm outside of Visual Studio*** will corrupt your project or not, you should know this:

there may be ***several installations of npm (and node.js) on your machine***. Node.js installer stores its packages in "*C:\Program Files\nodejs*" path by default and sets up the system ***PATH*** variable with this value. When you install packages via **-g** option, they are stored in *"%APPDATA%/npm"* path.

So, when you use npm **outside of Visual Studio**, system console will apply to the version of npm/nodejs which is ***stored in the PATH*** variable.

To make sure that you use the same version of npm in Visual Studio, open ***Tools/Options => Projects and Solutions/External Web Tools*** option. Visual Studio will use locations of external tools *by the order, as they are located in the list*.

You can add ***PATH*** variable and put it *in the first place* to use ***the same version as you system.console does***:

[image]
at this picture VS will use PATH variable, while "$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External" and "c:\Program files\nodejs" will be ignored (*although, I have redundancy here, because, my system PATH variable contains "c:\Program files\nodejs" as well*).

You can also *check version of each npm* installed on your machine. Just run ***"npm -v"*** in VS *package manager console*, and run it in your *system console*.

I have the same version for them because of my preferences:

```
node -v
v7.8.0
```

But when I run this command opening cmd at *$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External* path, I get an older version:
[image]

hope this helps =)